# Javscript Array to String (Automatic Conversion)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

New to JS, so still learning lots

I came across this (See Image) on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp

It states this "JavaScript automatically converts an array to a comma separated string when a primitive value is expected."

On their own website, this works fine and they state it should return the same result (String)

But when I try it on Chrome Console, I get the following results:

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log(fruits);

Result: (4) ['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango']

0: "Banana"
1: "Orange"
2: "Apple"
3: "Mango"
length: 4
```

Note: This returns an Array

---

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

console.log(fruits.toString());

Result: Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

Note: This returns a string

I someone could clarify which is the correct way, that would be much appreciated

Thanks

[image: Array to String]

Comment: `console.log` will log whatever you give it to log - an array will log as an array ... but  `console.log(\`${fruits}\`);` will do what you expected

Comment: I think this only applies to native method that expect a string such as innerHTML setter as the w3s suggest

Comment: "when a primitive value is expected" - yes, but `console.log` does not expect a primitive value.

Comment: W3Schools is widely known to have incomplete, out of date, or just flat out wrong information. Avoid it like the plague. Instead, use a more authoritative resources such as [The Mozilla Developers Network](https://www.mozilla.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.log` in modern browsers is a debugging tool that can display arbitrary objects and arrays for the developer to inspect. "conversion" makes non sense here, `console.log` just displays what it gets from you.

you can use `someArray.toString()` to convert an array to a string but I would strongly advise against that.
besser use `.join` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in order to have more control about the output.

also, MDN is a much better source of documentation for everything JS/web

Comment: Thanks for the help in clarifying and appreciate the tip on using (.join) instead

Answer (score 1):

> "JavaScript automatically converts an array to a comma separated string when a primitive value is expected."

Yeah, `console.log` is not one of those cases where a primitive value is expected, which is why you are not seeing that happen.

Actually `console.log` is will *usually* (this behavior is technically implementation-defined so you can't count on it across all environments) give a debuggable live view of the object when passed an object type (including arrays).

For an example of when this conversion happens with arrays, experiment with what happens when you set the `textContent` of a DOM node to the array.

Comment: Thanks for the help in clarifying, makes a lot more sense now.